# About selenium Test running in Eclipse

Tags: selenium

While running selenium test in eclipse I am getting below error message

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path
>   to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver
>   system property; for more information, see
>   https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver. The latest version can be
>   downloaded from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases   at
>   com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:754)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:124)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService.access$100(GeckoDriverService.java:40)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(GeckoDriverService.java:114)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:329)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.toExecutor(FirefoxDriver.java:150)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:120)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:98)
>     at AutomationFramework.FirstTestcase.main(FirstTestcase.java:9)

Can anyone suggest me how to fix it?

Comment: add the proper library for that in eclipse

Comment: share your code also

Comment: This is the code i used;
public class FirstTestcase {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
 
        //Launch the Online Store Web site
  driver.get("http://www.store.demoqa.com");
 
        // Print a Log In message to the screen
        System.out.println("Successfully opened the website www.Store.Demoqa.com");
 
  //Wait for 5 Second
  //Thread.sleep(5000);
  
        // Close the driver
        driver.quit();
 }

}
"

Comment: hi bhavik , Can you give me details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will work for old version of Selenium. After Selenium 3 you need to use gecko driver to work with Firefox. Download gecko driver and add below line in your code.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","G:\\Selenium\\Firefox driver\\geckodriver.exe");//give location accordingly for your gecko driver
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

For more info go through [this post](http://learn-automation.com/use-firefox-selenium-using-geckodriver-selenium-3/)

Comment: Thanks Shoaib its working for me

Comment: Then please mark my reply as correct.